# How to set authtoken in main.ts Vue3 vue/apollo-composable apollo/client

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo

I am using vue3 add apollo-composable & apollo/client for graphql client.
This is my main.ts configure file.

```
import {createApp, provide, h} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import {ApolloClient, InMemoryCache} from "@apollo/client";
import {DefaultApolloClient} from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import router from './router'
import './assets/sass/main.sass'

const defaultclient = new ApolloClient({
    uri: process.env.VUE_APP_API_HOST,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    headers: {
        "TOKEN": "....."
    }
})

createApp({
    setup() {
        provide(DefaultApolloClient, defaultclient)
    },
    render() {
        return h(App)
    }
}).use(router).mount('#app')
```

I don't know how to change the token in the view/Home.vue
I can get graphqldata but I want to change header option before useResult ....

```
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    UserListTable,
  },
  setup() {
    const { result } = useQuery(usersQuery)
    const users = useResult(result, null, (data: { userAccounts: any; }) => data.userAccounts)
```